# Out of order touch events in emulator when using host GPU on Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: android-emulator

I'm firing up an Android KitKat x86 Atom Emulator instance with the host GPU enabled. When I do so, some of the touch input events fed to the emulator kernel appear to be out of order. This only occurs when using Host GPU.

For example, below you can see what I believe is a valid tap (position + down followed by a position+up) but the next event is a down before the pointer position is changed.

```
$ adb shell 'getevent -l'
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 1: /dev/input/event0
 name:     "qwerty2"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter           
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_X                0000031e            
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                0000047a            
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN                
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_X                0000030b            
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                00000472            
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP                  
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN                
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_X                000000a0            
/dev/input/event0: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                00000147            
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP 
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

This makes it tricky to use the emulator with the host GPU. I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows a fix, or if it is something specific to my host / GPU drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this. This problem went away for me when I switched from noveau to the binary nvidia drivers for my GPU.  Still not sure what the root cause is but I did/do not have time to investigate further.